# Model structure with complex joins?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

If you have a complex database structure where many of your select statements involve complex joins is it best to use 1 model or do you have to break each table into it's own model?

For example if I have a database that has the following

- tb_persons = a list of people
- tb_interests = a list of interests assigned to each customer
- tb_interests_types = a list of all the    possible interests

And I need to pass data to my views from SQL statements like

```
select c.interest_type_name 
from tb_persons a
LEFT JOIN tb_interests b on (a.persons_id=b.persons_id)
LEFT JOIN tb_interests_types c on (b.interest_type_id=c.interest_type_id)
WHERE a.person_id=1
```

What model would this go into? Can you treat a model as a holder for a group of tables that relate together or do you need to have individual models?

Comment: Hi, you surely can use a model to work with a number of tables. Model basically covers a section of your website, not just a single table. That also depends on how big your project and database is, but to answer you question - yes, model is a holder for a group of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a person model, and then join the interests on an as-needed basis.

As stated in a comment, you don't need a model-per-table structure, but you probably need a model per strong entity (an interest is worthless without a "person" context, but a person object can be valuable without interests).